# react router - Router.js:111Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentLocation' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, react-router

I've been following this tutorial to get React Router working https://scotch.io/tutorials/routing-react-apps-the-complete-guide ... yet when I try and utilise any function of react router - it gives me this:

> Router.js:111Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'getCurrentLocation' of undefined
>       at Object.createTransitionManager (localhost:8080/public/bundle.js:22730:14)
>       at Object.componentWillMount (localhost:8080/public/bundle.js:22737:36)
>       at localhost:8080/public/bundle.js:15709:24
>       at measureLifeCyclePerf (localhost:8080/public/bundle.js:15436:13)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (localhost:8080/public/bundle.js:15708:10)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (localhost:8080/public/bundle.js:15619:22)
>       at Object.mountComponent (localhost:8080/public/bundle.js:8009:36)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (localhost:8080/public/bundle.js:15732:35)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (localhost:8080/public/bundle.js:15619:22)
>       at Object.mountComponent (localhost:8080/public/bundle.js:8009:36)

I've tried using webpack-dev-server as well... and still no joy - same issue. I can't find any other mention of this error... what could be the issue?

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { render } from 'react-dom';
 import {Router, Route} from 'react-router';

class Home extends Component {
render(){
    return (<h1>Hello</h1>);
}
}

render(
<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
</Router>,
document.getElementById('container')
 );'
```

Comment: What versions are you using of the packages? (Check package.json)

Comment: "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0"
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
   "webpack": "^1.13.3"

Comment: Never mind, it's part of version 3.0.0 which requires to pass a history option... I've downgraded to 2.8.1. for the time being

Comment: i think you have to pass `browserHistory` object exported from `react-router` to the `Router` component > `<Router history={browserHistory} ... />`

Answer (score 0):

yeah, i test it out, you need to pass history={ browserHistory } to your Router.

```
render(
    <Router history={ browserHistory }>
        <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('container')
 );
```

and don't forget import browserHistory:

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, Link, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
```

Comment: Hi there! Since the `'react-router'` has undergone considerable (breaking) changes during its version changes, specifying a valid `history` attribute might do the trick, depending on the OP's version of the `'react-router'` – regardless whether it's the `browserHistory`, `hashHistory`, or `memoryHistory`. Maybe also avoid adding unneeded dependencies in your answer, neither `Link` nor `IndexRoute` were mentioned by the OP ;)